# The code is right but sometimes i got a runtime error

Tags: swift, random, numbers, cycle

I write a function,inside this function there is a switch and in every case there are operations with random generated numbers
I call this function inside a for cycle for many times and copy the results into an array,and sometimes i get a EXC_BAD_Instruction error during execution, I don't understand why

I notice that if the cycle is longer the error show up more often,why?
What i have to do to use this code inside a bigger cycle without any error?

```
var operationNumber = random() % 4  

switch operationNumber {
case 0:
    number1 = random() % (biggestN + 1)
    number2 = random() % (biggestN + 1)
    result = number1 + number2
    operation = "+"
case 1:
    number1 = random() % (biggestN + 1)
    number2 = random() % (number1 + 1)
    result = number1 - number2
    operation = "-"
case 2:
    number1 = (random() % (biggestN + 1))+1
    number2 = (random() % (number1/2))+1
    result = number1 * number2
    operation = "x"
case 3:
    result = random()%biggestN
    number1 = (random()%biggestN)*result
    number2 = number1 / result
    operation = "/"
default:
    break
}
```

In the editor the line with the error is the one with case 0,so I think that the error is inside the switch

Thanks for the answers

Comment: "The code is right but sometimes i got a runtime error" That's an innovative way of saying "the code is wrong" :-)

Comment: It would help if you pinpoint the line where the error occurs.

Comment: the error occurs in case 0 but i tried to make a long cycle exluding a case at the time and i think that the problem is in case 2,but i don't know why

Answer (score 2):

You probably get a division by zero error in case 3. You should assert in this case that the `result` is not zero. One way is the following:

```
result = (random() % biggestN) + 1
```

EDIT:

The same can happen if `biggestN` is zero. So we can update to:

```
result = (random() % (biggestN + 1)) + 1
```

Comment: What about: result = (random() % (biggestN + 1)) + 1?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
case 0:
    number1 = random() % (biggestN + 1)
    number2 = random() % (biggestN + 1)
    result = number1 + number2
    operation = "+"
case 1:
    number1 = random() % (biggestN + 1)
    number2 = random() % (number1 + 1)
    result = number1 - number2
    operation = "-"
case 2:
    number1 = (random() % (biggestN + 1))+1
    number2 = (random() % (biggestN + 1))
    result = number1 * number2

    operation = "x"
case 3:
    result = (random()%biggestN)+1
    number1 = (random()%biggestN)*result
    number2 = number1 / result
    operation = "/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Junior is close, essentially the problem is that the denominator (left-hand operand) of both / and % is required to be non-zero and you have multiple cases where that condition isn't met.  The easiest fix is to replace your usage of `random` with `arc4random_uniform` which also will give you better distribution:

```
func pick(range:Int) -> Int {
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(range)))
}

func sampler(biggestN:Int) {
    var operationNumber = pick(4)
    var result:Int = 0
    var number1:Int = 0
    var number2:Int = 0
    var operation:String = "X"

    switch operationNumber {
    case 0:
        number1 = pick(biggestN + 1)
        number2 = pick(biggestN + 1)
        result = number1 + number2
        operation = "+"
    case 1:
        number1 = pick(biggestN + 1)
        number2 = pick(number1 + 1)
        result = number1 - number2
        operation = "-"
    case 2:
        number1 = pick(biggestN + 1) + 1
        number2 = pick(number1 / 2) + 1
        result = number1 * number2
        operation = "x"
    case 3:
        result = pick(biggestN) + 1
        number1 = pick(biggestN) * result
        number2 = number1 / result
        operation = "/"
    default:
        break
    }
}
```